# why is it possible to model a <<use>> dependency between an actor and a use case?

Tags: uml

Tools allow to create a use dependency between an actor and a use case even if the meaning of a such dependency is not clear and if no such dependencies are described in the norm ?

Comment: I would not mind too much if tools allow "illegal" models. Sometimes a domain demands strange models. It's the architect's responsibility to check model quality and whether modeling rules are applied in a certain domain.

Comment: @Kilian I did not say that the model is illegal, I said that it is not clear and not described in the norm. But I agree that in a specific context we can define the semantic of a use dependency between an actor and a use case. But by default, the semantic is not clear and not described in the norm.

Comment: Asking "why is it possible" implies you're thinking it might be wrong. Anyhow, the UML specs can't (and should not) cover every modeling scenario, though quite some parts of the docs should be more specific. I guess the OMG guys had (and have) long discussions as to what should be fixed and what should be left open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer contains two parts : one about the keyword << use >> and one about Dependencies usage.

Keyword: "UML keywords are reserved words that are an integral part of the UML notation and normally appear as text
annotations attached to a UML graphic element or as part of a text line in a UML diagram." (page 743)

One usage of keyword is (page 743): "To distinguish a particular kind of relationship between UML concepts (meta-association) from other
relationships sharing the same general graphical form. For example, dashed lines between elements are used
for a number of different relationships, including Dependencies, relationships between UseCases and an
extending UseCases, and so on."

The use keyword specifies an Usage dependency and an Usage dependency may be defined between two NamedElement.

Actor and UseCase are two NamedElement, so it is possible to model a << use >> dependency between an Actor and UseCase even if the meaning of 
a such relation is not clear and even if the specification said about Actor :"An Actor can only have Associations to UseCases, Components, and Classes. Furthermore these Associations
must be binary."

Comment: I know that the usage is not to answer to his own question, but it is for someone I know.

Comment: Well, answering your own question is not usual, but absolutely legal. It might help others.