# How to represent a dependency relationship between node and artifact in UML Deployment Diagram?

Tags: deployment, dependencies, uml, diagram, component-diagram

I have a web application that reads from a file. My application is represented as a node and file as an artifact. Can I use dashed arrow to represent their relationship ?

[image]

Comment: the file is a log file, a file produce by the artifact or a file you delivered ?

Comment: the file is a  log file generated by the application server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used artifacts as you want but it seems legal.

Artifact (p654) : An Artifact represents some (usually reifiable) item of information that is used or produced by a software development process or by operation of a system. Examples of Artifacts include model files, source files, scripts, executable files, database tables, development deliverables, word-processing documents, and mail messages.

A log file is produced by an operation of the system, I guess. Guys, what do you think ?

And there a stereotype in the standard profile: «Create» : A usage dependency denoting that the client classifier creates instances of the supplier classifier. (p 678)

So if you want to model that your wbe server creates an instance of LogFile, the following schema should do the job.

[image]

More remarks:

- the web server is an execution environment deployed on a node.
- your web application is an artifact running on the execution environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer granier. I don't need to model that my server writes log file. I want to model my web application that reads my log file.

Comment: your application reads the log file ? Is it a monitoring application ? Otherwise I can not figure why an application would read a log file. But even if this is for read, the stereotype is Create ... not Read ... :) If you want to model the read, a use dependency as you said is more  
suitable and you can add a note to precise the meaning of the use dependency.

Comment: Yes it's a monitoring application. It localizes every request received by my server. Could the stereotype <<uses>> be right? I cannot find no article that explains if this kind of relationship between a node and artifact is right!

Comment: @Lorenzo, See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181038/why-is-it-possible-to-model-a-use-dependency-between-an-actor-and-a-use-case#comment81318672_47181038 to have some information about <<use>>. It can be used between almost all UML meta-classes.

Answer (score 0):

That's perfectly ok. You could optionally stereotype the dependency with `<<create>>`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think  I'm going to use the stereotype <<use>>.  I think it's more appropriate.

Comment: I was referring to the comment "generated by", but `<<use>>` might indeed be more appropriate.